# VueJS - How do I just have one routing path to load the same component with different ID's

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I have three files and they are `router.js`, `App.vue` and `Contents.vue`:

**`router.js`:**

```
{
  path: '/views/frames/viewContentId1',
  name: 'letsCheck1',
  component: () => import('./views/frames/Contents.vue'),
  props: {
    id: '1'
  }
},
{
  path: '/views/frames/viewContentId2',
  name: 'letsCheck2',
  component: () => import('./views/frames/Contents.vue'),
  props: {
    id: '2'
  }
},
```

**`App.vue`:**

```
<div class=" Button to display content of Id1">
  <vs-button @click="$router.push({name: 'letsCheck1'}).catch(err => {})">Explore Light</vs-button>
</div>

<div class=" Button to display content of Id2">
  <vs-button @click="$router.push({name: 'letsCheck2'}).catch(err => {})">Explore Deep</vs-button>
</div>
```

**`Contents.vue`:**

```
<div class="Whole contents are present here">
  <p> Here this content is same for both the id</p>
    <span v-if="id === '1' ">Top Notch1</span>
    <span v-if="id === '2' ">Top Notch2</span>
  <p> Here again this content is same for both the id</p>
</div>
<script>
props: {
  id: String,
  required: true
}
</script>
```

I am actually looking to make code effective in `router.js`. I have specified the `id` twice, but suppose I want to add more `id`'s which have the same information to display with slight changes, as you can see in `Contents.vue`, I have shown the slight changes by using the `v-if` directive.

So I want to know how can I define the path only once and how to specify the `id` in the buttons, such that it loads the content by the respective `id`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do with dynamic-routing. Please check the [documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#reacting-to-params-changes).

Router.js

```
{
  path: '/views/frames/:viewContentId',
  name: 'letsCheck1',
  component: () => import('./views/frames/Contents.vue'),
  props: {
    id: '1'
  }
},
```

App.vue

```
<div class=" Button to display content of Id1">
  <vs-button @click="$router.push({name: 'letsCheck1',params: { viewContentId: '1' }})">Explore Light</vs-button>
</div>

<div class=" Button to display content of Id2">
  <vs-button @click="$router.push({name: 'letsCheck1',params: { viewContentId: '2' }})">Explore Light</vs-button>
</div>
```

Contents.vue

```
<div class="Whole contents are present here">
    <p> Here this content is same for both the id</p>
        <span v-if="$route.params.viewContentId === '1' ">Top Notch1</span>
        <span v-if="$route.params.viewContentId === '2' ">Top Notch2</span>
    <p> Here again this content is same for both the id</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i understood the dynamic routing with ease. Then i don't think so props are necessary here. One thing i wanted to know and that is in my contents.vue i am using id every where, i mean even in the api calls, that is the reason i was using props and was passing a value router.js.

Comment: with dynamic routing ,you can access param/query to the component directly.. props makes sense where there is no direct route mapping to the component. hope this make sense.

Comment: Yes it makes sense, can you please look at my updated question, what i did is i used the props in the contents.vue and then specified the value in the router path, so then all then contents with id tag would get the value that was given in the router path. But now i want to use one router path. And how can give proper value such that all api gets that value. I tried $route.params.viewContentId in the this.realContentApi

Comment: with new code, passing props id 1 and 2, this is static routing. you need to keep adding new route every time. with Dynamic routing, you do not need to. this is bad practice.

Comment: Yeah i got it but now i just want to pass the same value to the API end point also but with just $router.params.viewContentsId is not working, so i want to know how to do it .

Comment: you need to define like this `path: '/views/frames/:viewContentsId` . here `viewContentsId` is a placeholder

Comment: This is all done, then i am using the params in the button and have also specified the value for :viewContentId, i want to use same value specified to it in my api endpoint made in content.vue. I tried using $router.params.viewContentsId dint work out

Comment: Are you spelling it `viewContentId` or `viewContentsId`? You keep switching between the two

Answer (score 0):

This is a bad way in my opinion to reuse a component
Create a route like this: `/views/frames/:viewContentId
and use ad props in the component for identify the :viewContentId.
This is a smarter way for reusable the component, so:

```
{
  path: '/views/frames/:viewContentId',
    name: 'letsCheck1',
  component: () => import('./views/frames/Contents.vue'),
  props: true
},
```

And in Contenent.vue

<

```
div class="Whole contents are present here">
    <p> Here this content is same for both the id</p>
        <span v-if="viewContentId === '1' ">Top Notch1</span>
        <span v-if="viewContentId === '2' ">Top Notch2</span>
    <p> Here again this content is same for both the id</p>
</div>
<script>
props: {
  viewContentId: '',
  required: true
}
</script>
```